# Rename field in Mongoose response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is it possible to rename fields in my Mongoose query response?

In this example I'm selecting field `c` from my documents.

```
Test.find({a:b}, 'c', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Is there a clean way to rename the `c` field to something else?

Note that I would just like to rename it for this query only, not for other queries that will fetch `c`, nor for the database in general.